# How can I simplify my loop?

Tags: php

This is what I have for my php loop:

```
<?php
$VarC = 6;
$VarD = 2;
$varA = 1;
$varB = 2;
$VarAns = 0;
$ct = 1;
$ct2 = 1;

$VarAns = $varA * ($varB + $VarC) / $VarD;

while ($ct <= 10) {
    $VarAns = $varA * ($varB + $VarC) / $VarD;
    echo "X = $varA * ($varB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>";
    $varA = $varA + 1;
    ++$ct;
}

echo '<br>';

$varB = $varB + 2;
$varA = 1;

while ($ct2 <= 10) {
    $VarAns = $varA * ($varB + $VarC) / $VarD;
    echo "X = $varA * ($varB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>";
    $varA = $varA + 1;
    $ct2 = $ct2 + 1;
}

echo '<br>';

$varB = $varB + 2;
$varA = 1;
$ct2 = 1;

while ($ct2 <= 10) {
    $VarAns = $varA * ($varB + $VarC) / $VarD;
    echo "X = $varA * ($varB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>";
    $varA = $varA + 1;
    $ct2 = $ct2 + 1;
}

echo '<br>';

$varB = $varB + 2;
$varA = 1;
$ct2 = 1;

while ($ct2 <= 10) {
    $VarAns = $varA * ($varB + $VarC) / $VarD;
    echo "X = $varA * ($varB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>";
    $varA = $varA + 1;
    $ct2 = $ct2 + 1;
}

echo '<br>';

$varB = $varB + 2;
$varA = 1;
$ct2 = 1;

while ($ct2 <= 10) {
    $VarAns = $varA * ($varB + $VarC) / $VarD;
    echo "X = $varA * ($varB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>";
    $varA = $varA + 1;
    $ct2 = $ct2 + 1;
}

?>
```

What I'm trying to do is increment `$varA` by 1, til it gets to ten and '$varB' which starts at 2 and increments by 2 til 10...
Any ideas, I know there should be a way to simplify things, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Sounds like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I would do one loop, use 5 variables to store the echo items, then echo all 5 variables in the end.

Answer (score 0):

One loop with 5 values storing the results:

```
<?php
    $VarC = 6;
    $VarD = 2;
    $varA = 1;
    $varB = 2;
    $sA = "";
    $sB = "";
    $sC = "";
    $sD = "";
    $sE = "";
    $ct = 1;
    $newvar = 0;


    while ($ct <= 10) {
        $newvar = $varB;
        $sA .= "X = ".$ct." * (".$newvar." + ".$VarC.") / ".$VarD." is equal to: ".(($ct*($newvar + $VarC))/$VarD)."<br />";
        $newvar += $varB;
        $sB .= "X = ".$ct." * (".$newvar." + ".$VarC.") / ".$VarD." is equal to: ".(($ct*($newvar + $VarC))/$VarD)."<br />";
        $newvar += $varB;
        $sC .= "X = ".$ct." * (".$newvar." + ".$VarC.") / ".$VarD." is equal to: ".(($ct*($newvar + $VarC))/$VarD)."<br />";
        $newvar += $varB;
        $sD .= "X = ".$ct." * (".$newvar." + ".$VarC.") / ".$VarD." is equal to: ".(($ct*($newvar + $VarC))/$VarD)."<br />";
        $newvar += $varB;
        $sE .= "X = ".$ct." * (".$newvar." + ".$VarC.") / ".$VarD." is equal to: ".(($ct*($newvar + $VarC))/$VarD)."<br />";
        $ct++;
    }
    echo $sA."<br />".$sB."<br />".$sC."<br />".$sD."<br />".$sE;
    ?>
```

Comment: If my answer works for you, please mark it as an answer. thanks.